# Build promotion from 1 repo to other in artifactory if the build is not maven/gradle/ant..it is just a tar file

Tags: jenkins, build, automation, artifactory, devops

I want to promote a build that is a tar file from one repo to another in Artifactory.

I am pushing a build to Artifactory via a POST call from a Jenkins job and the directory structure in Artifactory is like this:`repository_name/build/build_name`.

When I am creating another Jenkins job to promote a build from 1 repo to other then it is asking build name and build number and I don't know from where I have to get the build name and build number.

Is there any way to get the build name and number for build promotion if the build is not maven or Gradle or Ant. It is just a tar file.?
or Is there any way to pass build name and build number while pushing a build to Artifactory?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would recommend making the 2nd job as a downstream job. Pass build name and number form first job to the second job. You can use JFrog CLI in the second Jenkins job to promote build's artifacts from one repo to other repo. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-BuildIntegration-PromotingaBuild